# Export an ASCII-armored GPG secret key removing the passphrase, while retaining passphrase-protection on keyring

Tags: gnupg, secret-key

I would like to **keep a GPG secret key passphrase-protected** in my personal keyring on my laptop, but also **export it as a passphrase-less ASCII-armored file** for use in an automated system that has its own secret-management.

At the moment, the best solution I have for this is:

- Edit the key on my keyring, removing the passphrase (using `gpg --edit-key <keyid> passwd` as in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/550538/46453)
- Export the key (using `gpg --armor --export-secret-key`)
- Re-edit the key on my keyring to re-add the passphrase.

Rather than adding and removing the passphrase, it would be nicer to just remove the passphrase as part of the exporting process on the ASCII-armored file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, GPG does not provide a direct option to export a passphrase-less ASCII-armored secret key. However, you can achieve a similar result by using GPG's capabilities to temporarily disable the passphrase during key export. Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. **Export the secret key without passphrase:**

   ```bash
   gpg --export-secret-key --armor --export-options export-reset-subkey-passwd <keyid> > secret-key.asc
   ```

   The `export-options export-reset-subkey-passwd` option will temporarily disable the passphrase for the exported subkey. The exported key will not have a passphrase, but your original keyring will remain passphrase-protected.
2. **Re-enable the passphrase on your original keyring:**

   ```bash
   gpg --edit-key <keyid>
   ```

   Within the GPG key editor, use the `passwd` command to set a passphrase for the key.

This way, you export the key without a passphrase, but you don't permanently remove the passphrase from your keyring. Remember to securely manage the exported ASCII-armored file, as it won't have passphrase protection.

Please note that GPG is designed to prioritize security, and having a passphrase on your secret key is considered a best practice. Be cautious when handling keys without passphrases, especially if they are used for sensitive operations.

Comment: Looks like support for `export-reset-subkey-passwd` was removed in gpg 2.1.0: https://dev.gnupg.org/T1753